# Building a set using multiple conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to build a set where multiple conditions can be met?

For example, let's say $z = 10$ and the set builder is
\begin{equation}
f(y) = \{ x: (y = 10 \rightarrow x = 1) \lor (y > 0 \rightarrow x = 2 ) \lor (y < 10 \rightarrow x = 3) \}
\end{equation}

I want $f(z) = \{1,2\}$.

Is how I have presented this correct? If not, how would I present this equation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your use of $\to$ (imply). I think you meant to use $\wedge$ (and) instead.

Look at the third term of your disjunction, since $z<10$ is false, the statement $z<10 \to x=3$ will be true for any $x$, hence $f(z) = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So if I change the function to $f(y) = \{ x: (y = 10 \land x = 1) \lor (y > 0 \land x = 2 ) \lor (y < 10 \land x = 3) \}$ then $f(z) = \{ 1,2 \}$?

Comment: @DavidPoxon Yes

Comment: Amazing, thank you!